# RGUI swirl package on Windows 7 - correct answers create errors

Tags: r, swirl

I am trying to submit my answers to the swirl program (R programming - Functions unit). No matter what answers I put in, even the ones that I know are correct, it asks me to repeat the question.

**For example,**

"Below we will create a function called boring_function. This function takes
the argument `x` as input, and returns the value of x without modifying it.
Delete the pound sign in front of the x to make the function work! Be sure to 
save this script and type submit() in the console after you make your changes."

```
    boring_function <- function(x) {
      #x
     }
```

**So I submit:**

```
    > boring_function <- function(x) {
       x
     }
    > submit()
```

**And it gives me this error:**

"Sourcing your script...
Not quite! Try again.
Make sure to delete the pound sign so the last expression in the function is just x."

If I skip this question, and go on to later questions, it does the same thing.

Do I need to uninstall/reinstall the swirl package or is there some other problem?

Thanks in advance.

---

The results of sessionInfo()

```
    R version 3.2.5 (2016-04-14)
    Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
    Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

     locale:
    [1] LC_COLLATE=English_Canada.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Canada.1252   
    [3] LC_MONETARY=English_Canada.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
    [5] LC_TIME=English_Canada.1252    

    attached base packages:
    [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

    other attached packages:
    [1] swirl_2.4.2

    loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
     [1] httr_1.2.1     magrittr_1.5   R6_2.1.3       tools_3.2.5    RCurl_1.95-4.8
     [6] curl_2.0       yaml_2.1.13    crayon_1.3.2   stringi_1.1.1  stringr_1.1.0 
    [11] digest_0.6.10  testthat_1.0.2 bitops_1.0-6
```

Comment: Could you run `sessionInfo()` and edit to include the output?

Comment: Also I would try reinstalling the package before asking the question.  You should check the easy stuff first.  P.S. welcome to SO--for a first question you have clearly put some effort into describing the problem.

Comment: I reinstalled the package but I am still getting the same error. I added the SessionInfo() information in the post above.